# Javascript e condicional switch, problemas ao salvar um valor dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery, arraylist, javascript-eventos

Bem eu ainda estou aprendendo um pouco mais sobre javascript, e estou usando um pouco de jquery ultimamente, esse código é um dos meus trabalhos mais recentes, trata-se de um editor de código.

**Como ele funciona?**

- Primeiro, temos algumas palavras armazenadas em uma arraylist e uma condicional switch.
- Segundo, capturamos os eventos com uma função `keyup` e ativamos também uma outra função que vai capturar todo o valor digitado pelo usuário dentro de um campo `<textarea>` supostamente comparando com as palavras de nossa arraylist e switch, e finalmente, jogando todo esse valor para uma `<div>`.

**Em algoritmo seria algo como:**

- Obtenha todo o valor digitado em `<textarea>`
- Verifique as palavras, salve as que não passaram na comparação em 'x', e em seguida salve aquelas que passaram (e que supostamente vão mudar de cor) em 'y'.
- Insira esse valor no elemento `div` especifico 'x' respeitando as regras anteriores (separando e reunindo as palavras que mudarão de cor (**mais**) as que não mudarão de cor).

**O meu problema:**

Quando um valor é digitado e passa por todo o processo de verificação, o resultado é inserido em nossa `<div>` mas logo depois de inserir uma nova palavra, aquela palavra que mudou de cor anteriormente é perdida, retornando a sua cor padrão.

**O problema em prática:**

- O usuario digitou `<iframe>` e esse resultado apos a verificação é inserido dentro de uma `<div>` como na foto a seguir:

[Imagem 1](https://ibb.co/bH1Hg8r)

- O usuario digitou `<iframe>` mas também apertou a tecla de espaço, e o valor anterior de `<iframe>` com a sua cor, foi perdido. Temos o seguinte resultado:

[Imagem 2](https://ibb.co/wc58qQx)

- E por fim, o ultimo problema que eu descobri, é que nada acontece quando colocamos uma outra palavra a frente ou depois:

[imagem 3](https://ibb.co/Pzg7fg1)

**Resultados que eu estou obtendo, resumidos em uma imagem + saída html):**

[Meusresultados](https://ibb.co/xs6vQ42)

**Os resultados que eu preciso obter (imagem + saída html):**

[Imagem 4](https://ibb.co/W2VXB6D)

[Imagem 5](https://ibb.co/RDbmJnv)

[Imagem 6](https://ibb.co/MMjPgVW)

**Para finalizar o tópico, vamos ao meu código:**

```js
 $( "textarea" )
   .keyup(function() {
    var a = ["test","div","<",">","iframe"];
 var b = new RegExp(a.join("|"), 'ig');
 var c = $( this ).val();
 var d = c.replace(b, function (x) {
  switch (c) {
   case "<iframe>":
   z = '<span class="high2">'+x+'</span>';
   return z;
   break;
   case "<div>":
   z = '<span class="high2">'+x+'</span>';
   return z;
   break;
   default:
      return '<span>'+x+'</span>';
  }
   });
  document.getElementById("boom").innerHTML = d;
   })
   .keyup();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
 .def {white-space: pre-wrap; overflow: auto; font-family: monospace; font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.5rem; caret-color: white;}
 .dark {resize: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1; color: transparent; background-color: transparent; float: left; width: 50%; height: 100px;}
 .darke {background-color: #444; color: white; position: absolute; float: left; width: 50%; height: 100px;}
 .high {color: blue; font-family: monospace; font-size: 1em;}
 .high2 {color: red; font-family: monospace; font-size: 1em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="target" class="dark def"></textarea>
<div id="boom" class="darke def"></div>
```

Obrigado, antecipadamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugestão: nomeie suas variáveis de forma mais clara. `a`, `b` e `c` podem ser qualquer coisa, e você vai acabar trocando as bolas em algum ponto.

No seu switch, o valor sendo "condicionado" é o `c`: O texto completo do `<textarea>`.

Claro que, assim, se seu texto no `<textarea>` não for exatamente o que está no `case`, a substituição não acontece.

Corrigi o código, veja abaixo:

```js
$( "textarea" )
.bind('input propertychange', function() {
    var keywords = ["test", "div", "<", ">", "iframe"];
    var regex = new RegExp(keywords.join("|"), 'ig');

    var text = $(this).val();
    var formatted = text.replace(regex, function (match) {
        switch (match) {
            case "<":
            case ">":
            case "iframe":
            case "div":
                z = '<span class="high2">' + match + '</span>';
                return z;
                break;
            default:
                return '<span>' + match + '</span>';
        }
    });
    
    document.getElementById("boom").innerHTML = formatted;
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
 .def {white-space: pre-wrap; overflow: auto; font-family: monospace; font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.5rem; caret-color: white;}
 .dark {resize: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1; color: transparent; background-color: transparent; float: left; width: 50%; height: 100px;}
 .darke {background-color: #444; color: white; position: absolute; float: left; width: 50%; height: 100px;}
 .high {color: blue; font-family: monospace; font-size: 1em;}
 .high2 {color: red; font-family: monospace; font-size: 1em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="target" class="dark def"></textarea>
<div id="boom" class="darke def"></div>
```

---

Note também que eu inclui `case "<"` e `case ">"`, e tirei o `<` e `>` dos outros cases. Isso porque o match da regex, dadas as suas keywords, não inclui esses caracteres para o `iframe` e para o `div`, por exemplo.

Além disso, dá pra melhorar a responsividade do seu editor trocando o `keydown` por `bind('input propertychange')`, que é bem mais rápido em detectar mudanças no `<textarea>` (e detecta cortar e colar também, mesmo sem o teclado!).

**Obs.:** Já aviso que esse código (não só o que eu mudei, o original também) vai ficar bem devagar para textos muito grandes, e pode precisar de algumas otimizações em termos de tratamento de texto.

Comment: obrigado! bem, eu gostei da forma com a qual você explanou o código. Felizmente eu revisei uma outra versão desse código que eu havia feito e acabei chegando onde queria, se você quiser dar uma olhada eu posso compartilhar na questão, pois uma ajudinha é sempre bem-vinda. hehe!

Comment: Nesse caso eu sugeriria criar outra questão, a menos que o problema persista x). De toda forma, minhas recomendações continuam a valer: cuidado com o nome das variáveis, e tente trocar o `keyup` pelo evento que eu passei.